# Why doesn't my model respect the constraints?

Tags: python, numpy, constraints, nonlinear-optimization

This is my code. I try to optimize the quantity of water to distribute from supply to demand nodes following the transport model. There are two constraints: The demand must be at least supplied, and you can't take more water than the supply it's capable to distribute; but the model doesn't respect this constraint.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint, Bounds

# Data
rho = 1000
g = 9.8
C = 140.0 #roughness coefficient
J = rho*g/(float(1e6)) #constant of function

capacity = [0.3875, 0.607,  0.374,  2.404, 3.614, 2.738, 0.037, 0.17, 0.17, 2.63] #Supply data
demand = [0.768, 0.315, 0.38, 0.463, 0.094, 0.46917, 0.095, 0.129, 0.24057, 0.55, 0.03981, 0.518, 0.5, 0.5, 0.13, 0.021, 0.03721, 0.01346] #Demand data

m= len(capacity)
n = len(demand)

x0 = np.array(m*n*[1]) #Initial point for algorithm


# In[59]:


#READ L and h FROM ARCGIS !!!
L = (314376.57, 277097.9663,    253756.9869 ,265786.5632,   316712.6028,    232857.1468,    112063.9914,    135762.94,  131152.8206,    132323.662, 130317.865, 122075.3889, 19631.25154, 138142.7709, 199325.3382, 84158.4,    235101.9755,    179347.7901,
240720.646, 203442.04,  180101.061, 192130.6375,    243056.677, 159201.2212,    217305.5288,    62107.01542,    57496.89496,    58667.73631,    56661.93936, 48419.46322, 79510.13244,  99019.39624, 154407.9883,   95586.40056,    190184.6256,    134430.4403,
212852.124, 175573.5184,    152232.5389,    164262.1152,    215188.1548,    131332.6989,    189437.0064,    34238.49309,    29628.37263,    30799.21398, 28793.41703, 20761.78967,  115739.8845, 128061.9941,   151819.9124,    131816.1526,    187596.5497,    131842.3643,
156956.6541, 119678.0484,   97801.96823,    108366.6453,    159292.6849,    75437.22891,    131189.4431,    26207.94379,    30046.38946,    30022.33382, 36499.1228, 39154.16025,   165461.956, 173516.5609,    197274.4792,    181538.2241,    233051.1165,    177296.9311,
49979.50696, 36283.5152,    62559.4986, 17708.03221,    53338.17961,    39298.0475, 165299.2185,    133051.7993,    136890.245, 136866.1894,    143342.9784, 145998.0158,   272305.8115,    280360.4165,    304118.3347,    288382.0797,    339894.972, 284140.7867,
52935.33231, 128934.6503,   143847.8851,    99104.57653,    28403.13658,    116496.7582,    153039.7581,    210249.5101,    214087.9557,    214063.9001, 220540.6891,   223195.7265,    262646.9939,    357558.1272,    381316.0454,    365579.7904,    417092.6828,361338.4974,
342896.306, 305617.7003,    291163.1238, 294306.2972,   345232.3368,    261376.8808,    319481.1884,    164282.6751,    159672.5546,    160843.396, 158837.599, 150595.1229,    196032.549, 53287.46567,    18072.73241,    111682.1505,    47867.52331,    13615.3853,
205103.065, 190406.5166,    197459.3, 17835.09, 170439.194, 137982.189, 15022.6557, 168504.7907,    171893.2364,    1711869.181,    178345.9697,    181001.0072, 102411.6421,   206745.8721,    267147.8785,    174880.4788,    302924.5158,    247170.3304,
14088.98864, 175008.1185,   183668.6115, 162951.6989,   106219.1172,    123766.1215,    47423.29471,    188503.6722,    192342.1179,    192318.06,  198794.8512, 201449.8887,   157030.5306,    335812.2893,    359570.2076,    229499.3673,    395346.8449,    33959.65954,
 193562.595,    156698.3255,    120368.67,  145386.92,  197099.806, 112302.1299,    174078.01,  22972.15,   22834.548,  22898.9,    20860.1683, 27742.407,  154363.5577,    139786.9169, 163892.2097, 179394.3768,  199558.9795,    144091.4906)

h= (75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 1320,   75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 898,    75, 75, 665,    75, 75,
1369,   602,    349,    602,    1966,   778,    3837,   0 ,0,   0,  0,  0,  3384,   1602,   423,    2996,   423,    423,
1028,   260,    8,  260,    1624,   437,    3496,   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3043,   245,    0,  2655,   0,  0,
1822,   1054,   802,    1054,   2418,   1231,   4290,   0, 0,   0,  27, 0,  3837,   1039,   637,    3449,   637,    637,
893,    0,  0,  0,  1490,   0,  3362,   126,    126,    126,    126,    126,    2908,   126,    126,    2521,   126,    126,
161,    206,    306,    306,    306,    306,    1706,   306,    306,    306,    306,    306,    1325,   306,    306,    781,    306,    306,
1952,   1185,   287,    1185,   2549,   1361,   4421,   767,    767,    767,    767,    767,    3967,   1648,   137,    3674,   585,    0,
303,    758,    758,    758,    303,    758,    842,    758,    758,    758,    758,    758,    564,    168,    168,    1550,   168,    168,
2,  384,    384,    384,    2,  384,    1205,   384,    384,    384,    384, 384,   824,    384,    384,    1829,   384,    384,
1954,   1185,   746,    1185,   2520,   1362,   4401,   466,    466,    466,    437,    437,    3974,   1175,   319,    3790,   574,    319)

K = np.zeros(m*n)
N = np.zeros(m*n)


# In[61]:

#Definition of Objetive function

def objective(x):
    global d
    sum_obj = 0.0
    for i in range(len(L)): 
        if x[i] < 0.01:
          x[i]=0
        if x[i] >= 0.276:
            d= 1.484
        elif 0.276 > x[i] >= 0.212:
            d= 1.299
        elif 0.212 > x[i] >= 0.148:
            d= 1.086
        elif 0.148 > x[i] >= 0.0975:
            d=0.881
        elif 0.0975 > x[i] >= 0.079:
            d = 0.793
        elif 0.079> x[i] >= 0.062:
            d = 0.705
        elif 0.062 > x[i] >= 0.049:
            d= 0.626
        elif 0.049 > x[i] >= 0.038:
            d= 0.555
        elif 0.038 > x[i] >= 0.030:
            d=0.494
        elif 0.030 > x[i] >= 0.024:
            d=0.441
        elif 0.024 > x[i] >= 0.0198:
            d= 0.397
        elif 0.0198 > x[i] >= 0.01565:
            d= 0.353
        elif 0.01565 > x[i] >= 0.0123:
            d= 0.313
        elif 0.0123 > x[i] >=0.0097:
            d= 0.278
        elif 0.0097 > x[i] >= 0.0077:
            d=0.247
        elif 0.0077 > x[i] >= 0.0061:
            d=0.22
        elif 0.0061 > x[i] >= 0.0049:
            d=0.198
        elif 0.0049 > x[i] >= 0.00389:
            d=0.176
        elif 0.00389 > x[i] >= 0.0032:
            d= 0.159
        elif 0.0032 > x[i] >= 0.0025 :
            d= 0.141
        elif 0.0025 > x[i] >= 0:
            d= 0.123
        K[i] = 10.674*L[i]/(C**1.852*d**4.871)
        N[i] = K[i]*x[i]**1.852*J+x[i]*J*h[i]
        sum_obj = sum_obj + N[i]
    return sum_obj

#Definition of the constraints 

GB=[]
for i in range(m):
    GB.append(n*i*[0]+n*[1]+(m-1-i)*n*[0])
P=[]
for i in range(n):
    P.append(m*(i*[0]+[1]+(n-1-i)*[0]))

DU=np.array(GB+P)

lb = np.array(m*[0] + demand) # Supply
ub = np.array(capacity + n*[np.inf]) # Demand


# In[62]:


# show initial objective
print('Initial SSE Objective: ' + str(objective(x0)))


# In[63]:


# optimize
bnds = Bounds(0.00, np.inf, keep_feasible=True)
cons = LinearConstraint(DU,lb,ub)
solution = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP',constraints=cons,bounds=bnds,options={'iprint':2,'disp': True})
x = solution.x
```

I don't know why, but finally my model give less water that the node need. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Not totally relevant, but check out lmfit.

Comment: Your objective is non-differentiable. SLSQP is meant for smooth functions.